# Is the Retail version of Rocksmith 2014 Steamworks?

Tags: rocksmith-2014

I lately revived my guitar skills and want to relearn picking techniques and other music related stuff. I also want to connect my Guitar to my DAW. Learning that I can use the Rocksmith Real Tone Cable for that, I wonder if the Retail Version of this Game is Steamworks or UPlay, since it is considerably cheaper to buy retail with the cable included.

The game is listed in the according [support article](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7480-wusf-3601), but can anyone confirm which DRM the Retail Version of Rocksmith uses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The retail boxed copy is Steam, yes.

Comment: Do you have any supporting documentation?  I'd recommend linking to it if you do.

Comment: @Frank the supporting documentation is in the question.

Comment: Why, so it does.  I totally missed that.

Comment: @kotekzot That is not conclusive enough for me. The game is Ubisoft. Therefore I suspect UPlay behind every corner >_>. I need some evidence  that the retail is Steamworks. Not going to bother with UPlay. I did once and when it tried to download the game (AC4), it disconnected every other service on my PC. Took me like 4 days to download AC4, which I would normally with Steam in 1 hour.

Comment: Do note that you still need an Ubisoft Account - But you don't need UPlay installed